# Remove Workbook_Open Code In the copy saved with Save As from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to force the user to save the newly filled template (created with VBA and the macros inside it) to avoid data loss when it reopens (so users don't have to delete the data after creating executing the program each time), and I [read](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/save-workbook-as-new-file.shtml#.UnvASXAbD7c) something about enabling and disabling events, and I tried it but no luck. It saves the same book but if I open it, it seems to be executing anyway. Is there anyway to strip the macros from that copy?

The only Macro I'd be interested in disabling and/or deleting will be the code inside the Workbook_Open because that's the one that calls the modules code and such... and I'm only interested in removing it from the copy that I'm saving with another name. Not the file the user opened in the first place.

Further explaination:

I required the code on Workbook_Open. Let me try to explain better, I have a sheet with all the code in it, when it opens among other things it asks you to select some input files in order to fill the workbook, after it's done, it asks the user to save the filled workbook as a copy, but when I open that saved copy, it's like i'm opening the first sheet. And I'd like to just show the filled template instead of acting like an exact copy. That's why I thought of removing the Workbook

Code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ThisWorkbook.Activate
MsgBox "Site Configuration List" & vbNewLine & "Generated Sucessfully", vbOKOnly, "SCL Generated Sucessfully"
MsgBox "Remember to save the file with a different filename" & vbNewLine & "The next time the program executes it'll erase all information contained in it", vbInformation
SaveWorkbookAsNewFile (Project & "_" & ProjectName)

Private Sub SaveWorkbookAsNewFile(NewFileName As String)
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim ActBook As Workbook
Dim CurrentFile As String
Dim NewFileType As String
Dim NewFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Prevents screen refreshing.
Application.EnableEvents = False
CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

NewFileType = "Excel Files 1997-2003 (*.xls), *.xls"

NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
InitialFileName:=NewFileName, _
fileFilter:=NewFileType)

If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=NewFile, _
FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
Password:="", _
WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
CreateBackup:=False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I found something similar [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/31480-how-save-workbook-without-macro.html) before but that really didn't helped me.

Comment: Just to confirm.. you want to remove `Workbook_Open` code or all the code?

Comment: Just the Workbook_Open, since that's the one that calls the Module Code, and the Module Code is Password protected, I don't see the need to remove that as well.

Comment: If you are not going to use the module code then might as well remove it? or do you require the module code? Also which MS-Office version are you using?

Comment: My answer will depend on your answers of the two questions that I asked in my last comment.

Comment: I do require it. Let me try to explain better, I have a sheet with all the code in it, when it opens among other things it asks you to select some input files in order to fill the workbook, after it's done, it asks the user to save the filled workbook as a copy, but when I open that saved copy, it's like i'm opening the first sheet. And I'd like to just show the filled template instead of acting like an exact copy. That's why I thought of removing the Workbook_Open content on the saved copy, to avoid this behaviour. Edited the question

Comment: If you're struggling with the CodeModule solution because it's removing the code from your template, then you'd just have to reopen the saved copy after you create it and remove the code from that before saving and closing it again.

Comment: No I am not talking about that. I mean in the new file, do you need the module code? Also which excel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using excel 2007. In the new file (Filled sheet) I don't require any code. I'd like just to show the information and that's it

Comment: I have posted the answer....

Comment: In that case, it seems to me that the easiest solution would be to create a new blank workbook and then copy the contents and formats from your template over to the new workbook. You could go through the trouble of trying to remove or suppress the code in the manner that it's been suggested, but that might actually be more trouble than just copying what you want over to a clean workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using excel 2007. In the new file (Filled sheet) I don't require any code. I'd like just to show the information and that's it – Splendonia just now

In such a case all you need to do is save the file as an `.xlsx` file. You don't have to do the dirty work of removing the code. This file will automatically be stripped of all the code.

Change the line

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=NewFile, _
FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
Password:="", _
WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
CreateBackup:=False
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFile, _
FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook , _
Password:="", _
WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
CreateBackup:=False
```

Also remember to change the `NewFileType` accordingly.

**EDIT**

> Oops, I forgot to say I might need to save it as a .xls file, the program in which the users need to upload this later does not support >excel2007 files – Splendonia 5 mins ago

To delete the `Workbook_Open`, use this code (TRIED AND TESTED). Courtesy [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx). Please do not forget to read the `Introduction` mentioned in the link before you try this code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteProcedureFromModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Dim StartLine As Long
    Dim NumLines As Long
    Dim ProcName As String

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    ProcName = "Workbook_Open"
    With CodeMod
        StartLine = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
        NumLines = .ProcCountLines(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
        .DeleteLines StartLine:=StartLine, Count:=NumLines
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to say I might need to save it as a .xls file, the program in which the users need to upload this later does not support >excel2007 files

Comment: `Oops, I forgot to say` Now you say that :) Updating my post with an alternative.

Comment: Well, come on now... let's not just do the work for him/her. :P This CodeModule solution is what I was suggesting, but it's also the same concept that the OP said didn't work for him/her at the end of his original question. You're kind of banking on the feeling that the OP couldn't modify the code correctly from the thread s/he referred to in order to suit his/her needs and you're just flat out doing the work for him/her... it's not an unsafe bet, but it's not exactly the most helpful one, either. Yes, I am that PC.

Comment: @BillN.: To be honest, I never went through the links that OP mentioned or you mentioned. I still haven't gone through them yet. I will now.

Comment: @BillN.: Ok the link which you mentioned just talks about the approach. Unfortunately this is one of those msdn links which are not at all helpful for a beginner :( As far as OP's link is concerned, it again talks about the concept but doesn't really shed enough light. One of the post there simply directs the user to Chip's main site which again is not so useful. I am never in favor of serving the food in the plate but in this scenario, it was required IMHO :) Please feel free to downvote it if you disagree :)

Comment: Your solution is, in my opinion, the correct solution... I just didn't want to provide it so bluntly to a person who is trying to learn and they did already say it didn't work for them (though I believe that was due to an misunderstanding on their part). I am definitely not knocking the solution, but I'm quite certain it's correct... that said, you are leaving out the part of where and how to run this procedure and it might leave the OP accidentally deleting the module from the template and not resulting file as intended.

Comment: `you are leaving out the part of where and how to run this procedure and it might leave the OP accidentally deleting the module from the template and not resulting file as intended.` No I am not. :) Please see the line `Courtesy Chip Pearson. Please do not forget to read the Introduction mentioned in the link before you try this code.` in my post

Comment: `Touché, sir; Touché. – Bill N. 2 mins ago` @BillN.: Like I mentioned in my last to last comment, if you disagree, feel free to downvote the post :) I won't mind :)

Comment: I just wanted to say, Thank You Siddhart :)

Comment: Hello again Siddhart, sorry to bother you but I don't know how else to contact you. Is "deleting the code from Open_workbook" the only way to save as "2003" not including macros? I need to save it as 2003 the same way I'm saving in 2007 without macros thanks to your answer.

Comment: if that is the only place where you have macros then yes, deleting them would save the file without macros

Comment: Another stupid question and really sorry to disturbe you. I applied Chip's code but I was wondering if there's any workaround so that Users don't have access to the code? Apparently the module needs to be unlocked, meaning I'd have to distribute the code unlock as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible in code... (watch Siddharth prove me wrong)..

One way I could think of doing this is to check for existance of a value in a dedicated cell before running the code..

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    If rng.Value = "run" Then

    'put code in here

    rng.Value = ""

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought of this, this would probably be a good fix, I haven't implemented it yet because I think there might a better solution (?) or maybe not.

Comment: This can be sketchy... you can theoretically make the value and the dedicated cell sufficiently random that it's entirely unlikely that the resulting file could not be mistaken for the template that runs the code, but Murphy's Law is a b*tch and you'd be taking a risk by preserving all of the code in the files and just relying on the hope that they end-user will never trigger it.

Comment: @BillN. Yes this is very true, sketchy is a good description.. But you do also have an easy way of being able to reinstate the value manually should you need the code to execute next time it is opened..

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why the link you provide did not work for you? I was going to suggest something similar... it seems as though if they're saving a new copy, then you could intercept this on the BeforeSave event and just remove the code from the module using the standard API. Take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443970(v=vs.60).aspx

This object is available to you in VBA and something like this should work fine for what you're explaining... but if it isn't then we'd help you better if you could explain where and why this isn't doing what you're expecting it to do.