# Why is Workbook.Open() triggered twice on Workbook.SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

I just need my users to use the automatically saved copy of my file on their desktop when the file is located on SharePoint.

It looks like the Workbook.Open is triggered on SaveAs, as it execute the same code twice. I want it to close the SharePoint file - and reopen the new file from users desktop, but it seams to respond with the same path.

I have tried this in ThisWorkbook code:

`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path
If Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 2) <> "C:" Then
MsgBox "This workbook will now be saved on you desktop. Please use it from your desktop location."

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & _
    "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    ThisWorkbook.Close

End If

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SaveAs (correct me if I'm wrong) on ThisWorkbook, it'll get you straight in the newly created file, instead of making a copy of itself and saving it in the same path. That's at least how I understood it since the MsgBoxes weren't triggered so it wasn't like the Workbook_Open got triggered again.

My workaround to not have it continue the code on it as follows, however when their C is virtually on the sharepoint (as I figured out mine is), the "C:" check is automatically True since your path will be from the sharepoint onwards (I noticed this with the second commented MsgBox):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim cFileName As String, cFileExists As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
'    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path
'    MsgBox Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 2)
    If Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 2) <> "C:" Then 'put your full path of original file here
        MsgBox "This workbook will now be saved on you desktop. Please use it from your desktop location."
        cFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Dekstop\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
        cFileExists = Dir(cFileName)
        If cFileExists = "" Then 'check if it exists already
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
            wb.SaveCopyAs cFileName
        Else
            MsgBox "This file already exists"
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
    
End Sub
```

This way you can't have it open after running the code however. What you can also try is:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846141/19353309

Edit:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim cFileName As String, cFileExists As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    If InStr(1, ActiveWorkbook.Path, Environ("Username")) > 0 Then Exit Sub 'if it's not original file, exit sub immediately, just don't put this file in a path with your name in it :p
    'I would have used "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") but this did not work with my copy.Path being part of the sharepoint even when the file is saved on C:\
    cFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5) & " - " & Environ("Username") & ".xlsm" 'this way both files can be open (can't have two workbooks with the same name open)
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    cFileExists = Dir(cFileName)
    If cFileExists = "" Then 'copy does not exist yet
        MsgBox "This workbook will now be saved on you desktop. Please use it from your desktop location."
        wb.SaveCopyAs cFileName
    Else 'copy exists
        MsgBox ("File already exists, opening this version")
    End If
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=cFileName
    wb.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: When using `wb.SaveCopyAs cFileName` the copy is saved on `cFileName` path, but **the name and reference to `wb` does not change**. I mean, `wb`,  `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbok` will be the same object. Because of that, before closing `Thisworkbook` the newly created workbook should be open...

Comment: If the use of SaveAs on ThisWorkbook, get you straight in the newly created file. Why is ThisWorkbook.Path the same? It wound explain why Workbook_Open() was run the secound

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to do it correctly. Since we save on the user's desktop and the full path when trying to open can actually be from sharepoint (i.e. http://www.sharepoint.be/C:\users\....\desktop\thisfile.xlsm and I don't know how to get that full path. Dir() seemed to work but open not for some reason, I'll fiddle some more after weekend.

Comment: If Workbook_open() was run a second time, there would have been more MsgBoxes popping up which they didn't. I'll see what I can do on Monday

Comment: @SveinArneHylland The edit should do it :)

Comment: In my environment SaveCopyAs ends with the Runtime Error 1004. And this code also runs Workbook_Open() twice.

Comment: Are you using the code from the Edit? Because I don't see how it would run it twice if you're saving the filename with the content that prevents it from running further than the first if. 
Does the path exist?

Comment: Thanks - I will just call this as 'resolved' - but it does not actually answer why my Workbook_Open() is called twice. I have even make a public variable that seam to die on the SaveAs command.

Public IsThisWookbookOpenRunningNow As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If IsThisWookbookOpenRunningNow = True Then MsgBox ("This macro is already triggered."): Exit Sub

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Path

Comment: Why it's called twice is because it technically opens a new workbook (the copy), which contains the same Workbook_Open() sub as the original. As for the Public variable, I have tested a bit but can't figure it out either, sorry. I've set it in the workbook, in a module with keeping both files open, doesn't seem to work. Only time it did stay true was when I tried rerunning the code without the second file open but not from one to the other workbook.